# Can you refresh a webkitdirectory folder result?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the webkitdirectory option of file input in HTML 5 to have a user specify a folder and then read in the files of that folder-

```
<input type="file" id="dir_input" webkitdirectory directory />
```

This all works fine. I want to extend this so that, at some point later on (5/10/15 minutes), re-read that same folder selected in order to catch any new files that may have been added since the user originally specified the folder.

Is this possible?

I looked at the event object that's returned during the change event but nothing associated with it is jumping out at me with respect to refreshing the object. I know I can set it's value to "" to reset it but I'm not sure how to re-specify the same folder.

Thanks!

Comment: that's pretty interesting question. so you would have to do some timer to wait for 5 minutes and then create an event that will be triggered after timer runs out. Looking forward to seeing other people's ideas on approaching this

Comment: I suspect you can't without further user interaction. The `FileList` has no notion of the directory itself, just relative paths of each file included in the first snapshot. And the `<input>` can't be activated programmatically; the first thing it does is abort if it wasn't activated by the user.